# How to dynamic_cast a pointer of a class with no virtual method?

Tags: c++, oop, llvm

I'm using the [llvm](https://llvm.org) library and I want to check if an llvm::Value * is actually an llvm::LoadInst * (llvm::LoadInst is inherited from llvm::Value).

But sadly, llvm::Value doesn't contain any virtual method! (Yes, even without virtual destructor) Is it possible to use `dynamic_cast` on a class without virtual methods, or is there any other way to do the type checking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In LLVM, there is a `llvm::dyn_cast<T>` that will use LLVM's internal constructs to dynamically cast from one type to another, as long as they are indeed valid casts - if you use the wrong type `T`, it will return a `nullptr`.

So something like:

```
llvm::Value *v = ... some code here ... 
...
llvm::LoadInst* li = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::LoadInst>(v);
if (!li) { ... not a LoadInst, do whatever you should do here ... }
else { ... use li ... }
```

Naturally, if you already DO know that `v` is a `LoadInst`, you don't need to check - but an `assert(li && "Expected a LoadInst");` will catch if you ever got that wrong.

Note that you don't use `T*` for `llvm::dyn_cast<T>`, as you would for the C+++ standard `dynamic_cast`.

This comment in the code for `llvm::Value` explains that there is no vtable exactly for this reason (http://www.llvm.org/doxygen/Value_8h_source.html#l00207)

```
   /// Value's destructor should be virtual by design, but that would require
   /// that Value and all of its subclasses have a vtable that effectively
   /// duplicates the information in the value ID. As a size optimization, the
   /// destructor has been protected, and the caller should manually call
   /// deleteValue.
   ~Value(); // Use deleteValue() to delete a generic Value.
```

Comment: A note about catching with `assert`, if the macro `NDEBUG` is defined (which some build-systems sets for release builds) the macro `assert` is expanded with nothing and so will not "catch" anything.

Comment: Perfect. While Google reimplements exception machinery as manually checked and rethrown error codes, LLVM guys build their own polymorphic type system. Let's reimplement C++ standard because we can!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, and hopefully, before you release your product, you test it in a debug build. And, assuming you have a good set of tests, it's then NOT going to crash due to a null pointer dereference. This is EXACTLY what assert is for - checking that you "got things right". If you are not SURE the `v` is a `LoadInst`, then using a condition is the right way to go.

Comment: @bipil: Yes, not my decision, and I'm pretty sure the decision was taken a very long time back, so the current compiler technology may not have "been there".

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use `dynamic_cast` on a class without virtual methods,

There is no way to use `dynamic_cast` if the input is not pointer or reference to a polymorphic type, i.e. does not have any `virtual` member functions.

> or is there any other way to do the type checking?

I can't think of any. Your best option is to use `static_cast` but then you must be very certain that the type to which you are casting is valid.

```
struct Base { ... };
struct Derived1 : Base { ... };
struct Derived2 : Base { ... };

void foo(Base* base)
{
    Derived1* ptr = static_cast<Derived1*>(base);
    // Use ptr
}

void bar()
{
    foo(new Derived1()); // OK.
    foo(new Derived2()); // Not OK since foo assumes that the pointer 
                         // really points to a Derived1 object.
}
```